# Django WSGI list enabled modules

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, x-sendfile

I am using Django on Apache with mod_wsgi. I would like to use X-Sendfile for sending files, but with fallback when the X-Sendfile is not available.

Is there any way to list loaded Apache modules or to check whether the X-Sendfile is enabled or not directly from Django? I tried to dump the request variable, but there's no such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add into Apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_xsendfile.c>
Setenv apache.modules.mod_xsendfile On
</IfModule>
```

The request meta variables, ie., WSGI environ dictionary, would then have an entry for 'apache.modules.mod_xsendfile' with value 'On'. You can check for presence of variable and modify behaviour accordingly.